# What are the differences between most, more and less?

Tags: command-line, less, more, most

I'm now using Arch Linux, and find a command `most` works like `more` and `less`. To understand the differences between them is a confusing problem. The question [Isn't less just more?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604/isnt-less-just-more) mentions the differences between `less` and `more`. Do you know the differences on color performance, shortcuts and ability moving forward and backward?

Comment: according to the man page it's pretty much like `less` but can do multiple windows

Comment: it seems `less` can't perform color. Run `ls | less` and I get something unreadable.

Comment: @MaxfanZone: Try `ls --color=yes | less -R`. `ls` usually disables its text coloring when it's piping to something. `less` needs `-R` to pass ANSI escape characters to the screen or `-r` to pass escape all characters to the screen.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman: Thanks, that worked, I didn't add -R to less.

Comment: In the special case of the man command, you can set the PAGER environment variable to any one of these pagers or to anything else that works to use as the pager for man pages. Here's one I wrote that uses your favorite browser as a pager so you don't have to use a new set of key bindings. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54584985/kman

Comment: **`most` works *more* *or* *less* like `more` and `less`** - FTFY.

Comment: **TL;DR** use `less` because `more` is useless.

Comment: Of course there is also `pg`.

Comment: @JdeBP - `pg` isn't included on some distros.

Answer (score 359, accepted):

**more**

`more` is an old utility. When the text passed to it is too large to fit on one screen, it pages it. You can scroll down but not up.

Some systems hardlink `more` to `less`, providing users with a strange hybrid of the two programs that looks like `more` and quits at the end of the file like `more` but has some `less` features such as backwards scrolling. This is a result of `less`'s `more` compatibility mode. You can enable this compatibility mode temporarily with `LESS_IS_MORE=1 less ...`.

`more` passes raw escape sequences by default. Escape sequences tell your terminal which colors to display.

**less**

`less` was written by a man who was fed up with `more`'s inability to scroll backwards through a file. He turned `less` into an open source project and over time, various individuals added new features to it. `less` is massive now. That's why some small embedded systems have `more` but not `less`. For comparison, `less`'s source is over 27000 lines long. `more` implementations are generally only a little over 2000 lines long.

In order to get `less` to pass raw escape sequences, you have to pass it the `-r` flag. You can also tell it to only pass ANSI escape characters by passing it the `-R` flag.

*See `less` FAQs for more details: http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/faq.html*

**most**

`most` is supposed to be more than `less`. It can display multiple files at a time. By default, it truncates long lines instead of wrapping them and provides a left/right scrolling mechanism. [most's website](http://www.jedsoft.org/most) has no information about `most`'s features. Its manpage indicates that it is missing at least a few `less` features such as log-file writing (you can use `tee` for this though) and external command running.

By default, `most` uses strange non-vi-like keybindings. `man most | grep '\<vi.?\>'` doesn't return anything so it may be impossible to put `most` into a vi-like mode.

`most` has the ability to decompress gunzip-compressed files before reading. Its status bar has more information than `less`'s.

`most` passes raw escape sequences by default.

Comment: My head... all these double-entendres...

Comment: “`less` is more, but more `more` than `more` is, so `more` is less `less`, so use more `less` if you want less `more`. (...) If `less` is more than `more`, `most` is more than `less`.”
 —Slackware Linux Essentials

Comment: @AlberteRomero LOL

Comment: @AlberteRomero That's it, more or less, at least most-ly,. LOL I really like the horizonital scroll in most.

Comment: @JonasWielicki done: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271251/is-there-any-way-of-changing-most-keybindings-to-something-more-familiar/271252#271252

Comment: I just tried `most` because it colours man pages nicely, however I don't think it supports regular expression searches. Also, having to mess around with a `~.mostrc` file to get *vi-like* keybindings leaves me wanting `less`. Sometimes `less` is `more` than `most` :)

Comment: Just wait til you see `notquite`

Comment: @J.A.Corbal Fantastic. I was reading this in public and could not stop laughing. No one around me would get it. So I just kept laughing `more`.

Comment: @J.A.Corbal this makes a lot more sense thanks to your `code highlighting`

Comment: re: "`most` has the ability to decompress gunzip-compressed files before reading" -- you can just use `zless` or `...|gunzip|less`

Comment: @vol7ron `notquite` was an interesting project but since has been obsoleted by the ultimately perfected implementation `none`.

Comment: @startfry `most`'s manual speaks about regular expressions but what they say isn't clear at all and I never found a way to use them in `most`. And if you like colors, there is [a way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149614/less-command-change-color-of-and-end) to do the same with `less`.

Comment: Waiting for `least`, which will be more than `most`.

Answer (score 59):

Short answer:

Just use `less` and forget about `more`

Longer version:

`more` is old utility

You can't browse step wise with more, you can use space to browse page wise, or enter line by line, that is about it.

`less` is `more` + more additional features

You can browse page wise, line wise both up and down, search

Comment: If "more" is lacking for you and you know a few vi commands use "less"

Answer (score 22):

There is one single application whereby I prefer `more` to `less`:

To check my LATEST modified log files (in `/var/log/`), I use
`ls -AltF | more`.

While `less` deletes the screen after exiting with `q`, `more` leaves those files and directories listed by `ls` on the screen, sparing me memorizing their names for examination.

(Should anybody know a parameter or configuration enabling `less` to keep it's text after exiting, that would render this post obsolete.)

Comment: The parameter you want is `-X` (long form: `--no-init`). From `less`' manpage: `Disables  sending  the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.  This is sometimes desirable if the deinitialization string does something unnecessary, like clearing the screen.`

Answer (score 17):

### Summary

`more`, `less` and `most` are three pagers, we can compare them this way:

> `less` is more than `more`,
> `most` is more than `more`, approximately,
> `less` and `most` are different, none is better.

### More

- `more` is a very basic pager, where you can configure almost nothing.
- It uses Vim key bindings by default, and you can't change them.
- Sometimes you have to use `more` and can't use another pager instead, for example in long output (like `:highlight`) in `vim`, you can do `set more`, but you can't `set less` or `set most` instead. Actually, I'm not sure `vim` uses the true `more` because some features like search are missing.
- It supports colors (it can display 256 colors output where `most` can't).
- You will quit easily, sometimes by accident, for example if you search a pattern and it isn't found, `more` is exited (`less` and `most` don't behave that way).

### Less

- `less` is based on `more`, with extra features.
- Shortcuts are also Vim-based but they can be changed (they are changed in a strange way with `lesskey`).
- Can edit the file with an editor like `Vim` (it means you can have `more` in `vim` in `less`).
- There is an environment variable called `LESS_IS_MORE` to make `less` behave mostly like `more`.

### Most

- `most` isn't an improvement of `less` or `more`, it's a different software with a similar but not identical behavior.
- It's not always installed by default.
- Can edit file with an editor too.

## Most VS Less

Both `less` and `most` have features that the other don't have.
I sometimes see, like in [this website](https://www.slackbook.org/html/file-commands-pagers.html),

> If less is more than more, most is more than less.

Or on this post:

> most: less is more than more, most is more than less. Whereas the other pagers can only display one file at a time, most is capable of viewing any number of files

Actually, you can load several files on `less` with a command like `less foo bar`: it will display the file `foo` but you can see `bar` with the command `:n`.

### What Less can do and Most can't

- regex search, with `/`. Actually, `most`'s manual says search routines "use regular expressions", but I'm not sure there is a way to use them (the manual does not explain how).
- Reverse search direction with `N`. With `most`, the only way is to do again the last search with `?` and then you can move backward only).
- Filter, with `&`: display only matching lines. It's a bit like a `grep` but you keep the same shortcuts you had before.
- Vim-like marks: you can mark a position in text for every letter. `most` has only one mark, so you can lose the `most` mark by accident (overwrite it with another text position).
- Half-screen scroll. `most` only has page-up and page-down. If your screen can see 30 lines and you want to see important stuff on line 20 and line 40 at the same time, it can be done with half-screen scroll, but not with only screen scroll. It can look a bit irrelevant but it's not, after reading lots of manpages, I can see the difference (I also mapped a similar feature in Vim instead of "search letter in line" (default is `f` and `t`)).
- Go to matching () {} [] or any match you want to define.
- There is more information in `less`'s manual than in `most`'s manual (1102+300 lines vs 270 lines, depends on terminal size).
- `less` can display (at least) 256 colors, and `most` can display only 8 colors.
- `less` can also display text formatting like bold, blinking etc. with for example `\e[5m`, and `most` can't.

### What Most can do and Less can't

- Split screen vertically (can only cut screen in half and can't resize it, can be done several times).
- Configure it with a single config file.
- Binary mode, that looks like `xxd`.
- With `most`, you have colors in manual by default. For `less`, there is [a way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149614/less-command-change-color-of-and-end) to do the same but it's not the default behavior. That's probably a reason why some people think `less` can't do the same. If you still want `most` to be your manpager, then do `export MANPAGER=most`.

Answer (score 11):

> `more`, `less` and `most` are a terminal pagers or paging programs used to view the contents of text file.

**more:** `more` is a very basic,oldest and popular pager. `more` is originally allowing only forward navigation through a file, though newer implementations do allow for limited backward movement. i.e. `more` can move forwards and backwards in text files but cannot move backwards in pipes.

**less:** `less` is a more advanced pager that allows movement forward and backward, and contains extra functions such as search.  `less` does not have to read the entire input file before starting, so with large input files it starts up faster than text editors like `vi`.

**most**: `less` is more than `more`, `most` is more than `less`. Whereas the other pagers can only display one file at a time, most is capable of viewing any number of files,

Comment: `most` is more than `less` only for some features like split screen (and display different files in split), but there is also stuff that only `less` can do like filter (see my comment below)