# How to set background color of $PAGER?

Tags: colors, cat, man, less, pager

I usually set my terminal with transparent background. But, when I need to read a lot of text such as `man`, `less`, `cat`, etc., I want my background color to be solid black. I can change the backgrounds of `vim` and `w3m`. How to change the backgrounds of `$PAGER`, `man`, `less`, `cat`, `more` etc.? I'm on `Debian-Buster` using `zsh` shell with `colored-man-page` plugin installed.

Comment: A "terminal" with a transparent background would be impractical as a hardware device; you are talking about some `xterm` (software terminal *emulator*)? Likewise you cannot set the background of a pager; you could set the background color of the terminal (independent from the pager being used). Please edit the question to be more clear!

Answer (score 0):

That's actually multiple questions, where some have no useful answer:

- `cat` "could" be wrapped in an alias (capturing **some** of its uses), to set a particular background color, but whatever it sends to the terminal can change that background.
- `$PAGER` and `more` are redundant: you're unlikely to use anything but `less` underneath.  The same applies to `man` (which uses `$PAGER`).
- For `less`... the basic problem is that it is designed to color the **text** on the screen, and is almost completely agnostic regarding the background color.

Referring to

- [*Documentation on `LESS_TERMCAP_`* variables?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108699/documentation-on-less-termcap-variables) and
- [*Less command change color of “~” and “(END)”?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149614/less-command-change-color-of-and-end),

there's some mention of foreground (text) and background color.  However, those do not mention that the terminal responds to this (used for resetting the **bold** attribute):

```
me      sgr0      turn off bold, blink and underline
```

by resetting colors as well.  (It uses the same solution for resetting **blink**, but you are less likely to find that to be a problem).  It does use a different string for resetting underline, so that part of **`me`**'s description does not apply.

To make **`less`** use a particular color scheme, you would have to construct environment variables as suggested in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150322/105132), fooling **`less`** into setting the background color when it is turning off bold or blink.