# Is there any way of changing most keybindings to something more familiar?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, pager, most

`most` pager is nice, but its default keybindings are unlike any other.

As I don't want to learn a whole new set of keybindings for my pager (no matter how fancy and wonderful it is), is there any way of making `most` hotkeys feel more like `vi`, `less` and others?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`most` hotkeys are highly configurable. The settings are customized with `~/.mostrc` file.

Actually, your `most` package most likely comes with `lesskeys.rc` example configuration, somewhere in the documentation folder (*it's `/usr/share/doc/packages/most/lesskeys.rc` for me on openSUSE Leap 42.1*).

You just need to copy that file's contents into your `~/.mostrc` and you're done: you now have `less`-like keybindings in your `most`!

Comment: its `lesskeys.rc` is placed at `/usr/share/doc/most/lesskeys.rc` for my ubuntu based system

Comment: On my fedora 36, it is under `/usr/share/doc/most`