# less or more - which to use when?

Tags: less, more

`less` and `more` seem to have very similar functionality in that they both page through text a screen at a time.

What reasons are there to use one over the other?

Comment: As the saying goes, you get *more* with *less*.

Comment: Mostly the same as [Isn't less just more?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/604/isnt-less-just-more). See there too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`more` is a legacy program, and `less` is an improved version of `more` (the ability to scroll backwards being the biggest difference, but there are others such as searching within the text). Unless you're working on either a truly antique system or a pared-down embedded one where `less` isn't available, there is no reason to ever use `more`.

Comment: less does more.

Comment: @eccstartup more or less. [Most](http://linux.die.net/man/1/most) is best, though.

Comment: Not just antique, also embedded. The `less` program needs to buffer the entire output, which can easily exhaust memory on a small device. Also, darn youngsters should get off my lawn!

Comment: @SimonRichter I've never worked with embedded systems, but now that you've mentioned it that makes sense.

Comment: @SimonRichter: `less` doesn't need to buffer the entire output, it buffers 64k by default. See the `-b` and `-B` options. Also, `less` runs perfectly well on embedded, it's just that it's a relatively big program, and `busybox` already provides its own simplistic versions of `less` and `more`.